# Issue with list the addresses in list format?

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I need to display the list of addresses in a proper manner. How to get the address list in the following manner.

[image]

My code code is as follows,

```
 <div id="shopsDiv">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Bangalore Central Mall,FM Cariappa Rd Bangalore, Karnataka 560001</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum Mall,21, Hosur Rd, Koramangala, Bangalore, Karnataka 560095</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Urvashi Theatre, No. 40 Lal Bagh Rd, Bangalore, Karnataka 560027</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
```

But I didn't get the exact format. How to get the format as shown in image.

Comment: I didn't write any css code

Comment: provide your jsFiddle

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/T7ETg/1/)

Comment: Yes similar to it. But I need line visible between each list item

Comment: What do you mean by lines visible?

Comment: [Do you mean like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/T7ETg/2/)

Comment: Horizontal line between each address.

Comment: [I think this is how you want it, am i correct?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/T7ETg/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to refer to the [**jQuery Mobile Listview API Documentation**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/), ***Text Formatting and Count Section***.

You'll see that you need markup like the following:

```
                <li><a href="#">
                    <h3>Bangalore Central Mall,</h3>
                    <p>FM Cariappa Rd Bangalore, Karnataka 560001</p>
                    <span class="ui-li-aside">3.9 miles</span>
                </a></li>
```

To produce [**THIS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/7taTd/)